# How to redirect after the file upload completes?

Tags: php, jquery, html, asp.net, redirect

I am using this form and wanted to redirect only when the file uploads completes .

```
       <form name="sentMessage" id="quote" enctype=&quot;multipart/form-data&quot;> 
         <div class="input-field"> 
            <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" 
                   id="name" required
                       data-validation-required-message="Please enter your name" />
                       <label for="name" class="">   Name </label> 
              <p class="help-block"></p>

             </div>     
                <div class="input-field"> 
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" required
                       data-validation-required-message="Please enter your email" /> 
                       <label for="Email" class="">   Email </label> 
        </div>  
        <div class="input-field"> 
            <input type="text" name="subject" class="form-control" 
                   id="subject" required
                       data-validation-required-message="Please enter Subject" />
                       <label for="subject" class="">   Subject </label> 
              </div>
               <div class="input-field"> 

               <select class = "browser-default form-control extra" aria-required="true" name="selectType" required aria-invalid="false" required >
                 <option value = "" enable selected>Select Service</option> 
                  <option value = "1">L</option>
                  <option value = "2">V</option>
                  <option value = "3">D</option>
               </select>
            </div>
               <div class="input-field"> 
                 <textarea name="message" rows="10" cols="100" required class="form-control materialize-textarea" 
                       idation-required-message="Please enter your message" minlength="5" 
                       data-validation-minlength-message="Min 5 characters" 
                        maxlength="999" style="resize:none"></textarea>
                         <label for="message" class="" >   Message </label> 
          </div> 
<br>
        <div class="Attachment">  Attachment:<INPUT TYPE="file" NAME="image" MAXLENGTH=50 ALLOW="text/*" ></INPUT></div>
<br>
         <div id="success"> </div> <div class="hidden alert alert-success"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button><strong><span id="userName"></span> Your Message has been sent successfully, </strong>You will hear from us within 24 hours. </div> <!-- For success/fail messages -->
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary waves-effect waves-dark pull-right">Send</button><br />

          </form>
```

and this is the script I am using which executes after onlick submit button.

```
<Script>
        document
  .getElementById("quote")
  .addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
     window.location.href = "test.php"; 


  }); 

    </script>
```

but the issue is when I upload the file , and click on submit button it redirects to the url without submitting the form data with attachment . I want that once the upload is completed and a success message is shown then it need to be redirected not before that.

Comment: Your submit handler doesn't post the form data to any backend script, so naturally it isn't going to upload any file data. Also, you don't really need to use DOM to setup the handler, you can just do `<form name="sentMessage" id="quote" enctype="multipart/form-data" onSubmit="handleSubmit()">` and then in your javascript have a function like `function handleSubmit() { ... }` that sends the form data to your backend, and then does the redirect.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to what Michael said:

> e.preventDefault();

This is preventing the form from being submitted and the subsequent line is triggering the redirect.

You need to manually send the data to the backend and once it has been sent, execute the redirect.